# Adding Iservicefactory scope automapper not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I was using Automapper to mapped the Dto and entity.
Earlier automapper was working but when I added code to created the Iservicefactory scope in one of the function, then automapper is throwing an exception. Can someone please help with that.

```
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var dbContect = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
Getmapping(lstMessage)


List<MessageEntity> Getmapping(MessageDto lstMesage)
{
    return  Mapper.map(lstMesage, lstMessageEntity);
}
    
    public class MessageDto ()
{
public string TypeId{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class MessageEntity ()
{
  public int TypeId{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}

Before adding scope, GetMapping() method was working fine. now it is giving and exception 

Mapping types:
MessageDto  -> MessageEntity

Type Map configuration:
MessageDto  -> MessageEntity

Destination Member:
TypeId
```

I am adding an DI for automapper using CreateMap<MessageDto,MessageEntity>() and same is being added into DI. I have also added string to int conversion during mapping.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? Can you add your exception details to your question please?

Comment: @DubDub,
here it is.
Error Mapping type.
Mapping types:
MessageDto  -> MessageEntity

Type Map configuration:
MessageDto  -> MessageEntity

Destination Member:
TypeId

Comment: @ManojRaut Firstly, do not put important information like exceptions in comments, its really hard to read. Secondly, when someone asks for an exception, we want, the full Stacktrace, Exception type and Exception message, including any inner exceptions (just do a `Exception.ToString()`).